# In Application Insights, how can I avoid sending session custom data with every request?

Tags: .net, azure-application-insights

I'm currently using Application Insights in a WPF application. I handle almost everything manually, so on startup I create a telemetry client and set multiple Context properties like Database Version, Available RAM, Number of Monitors, etc. This is information that we use to segment and filter our telemetry data.

The problem I have is that all this information is sent every time with each call to the telemetry client (TrackPageView, TrackEvent, etc). Is there any way to send the information only once per session but still have it available to filter and segment in the portal?

Here's an extract of my code:

```
private static TelemetryClient _telemetry;

public static void Initialize(DeviceInfo deviceInfo, ApplicationInfo appInfo) {

    _telemetry = new TelemetryClient(TelemetryConfiguration.Active);
    _telemetry.Context.Device.OperatingSystem = deviceInfo.OsVersion;
    _telemetry.Context.Device.Id = deviceInfo.ProcessorId;
    _telemetry.Context.Component.Version = appInfo.Version;
    _telemetry.Context.Session.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    _telemetry.Context.User.Id = appInfo.UserId;

    _telemetry.Context.Properties["Cpu"] = deviceInfo.Cpu;
    _telemetry.Context.Properties["NumberOfMonitors"] = deviceInfo.NumberOfMonitors;
    _telemetry.Context.Properties["TotalAvailableMemory"] = deviceInfo.TotalAvailableMemory;

}

public static void TrackPageView(string pageName) {
    _telemetry.TrackPageView(pageName);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no "built in" way to send some of that data only once with each session.

If there was, then there'd have to be a `sessions` table, and you'd have to join between that `sessions` and `customEvents`/`pageViews` in every query to get that info. and then there's some tricks that have to be done to still let you update things as the session goes along (what happens if someone plugs in a monitor while the app is open?)

*As an alternative,* you could create a single event that *you* only send once yourself that has that information.

But if you do that, you'd have to again, start joining to that specific event, and you'd lose the ability to easily ask questions like "how often do people do X with 2 monitors", which you can trivially do right now.

Comment: That's what I suspected, but I wasn't sure if I was missing something obvious. Good to know anyway.